# angular's error message " Failed to instantiate module" only in explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a chat application with angular on the front end.

I added a new function called isUserTyping to the controler of the chat and tested in on chrome. it worked fine.

in explorer however the page does not load with that function (once I remove it it works fine).
Ther error I get in the consoelo is this:

***"SCRIPT5022: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mymodule due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mymodule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."***

I don't know what this error means.... I attached below the code I have.

If someone has any idea to what causes this in explorer I will greatly appraicate it.

script js:

```
var mymodule = angular.module('mymodule', ['ngRoute']);
mymodule.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/enter.html',
    controller  : 'SharedController'
  }) 
  .when('/chat', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/chat.html',
    controller  : 'cntrlChat'
  });
});


mymodule.factory('myService', function() {
 var savedData = {}
 var set=function (data) {
   savedData = data;
 } 
 function get() {
  return savedData;
}

return {
  set: set,
  get: get
}

});

mymodule.controller('SharedController', ['$scope', 'myService','$location',
  function($scope, myService, $location){ 

    $scope.updateMsg = function (msg) {
      myService.set(msg);
      $location.path("chat");
    }

    $scope.getMsg = function () {
      $scope.message = myService.get();
    }

  }]);

mymodule.controller("cntrlChat", ['$scope', 'myService','$q','$timeout',
  function($scope, myService,$q,$timeout){ 
   var socket = io();
   $scope.messages = [];
   $scope.room= myService.get();
   socket.emit('room', $scope.room);

   $scope.submit=function(){
    socket.emit('chat_message',{ room: $scope.room, msg: $scope.room+": "+$scope.insertedText });
    $scope.insertedText='';
    return false; 
  }

  socket.on('chat_message', function(msg){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.messages.push(msg);

    });
  });

  socket.on('info_message', function(msg){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.info=msg;

    });
  });


  $scope.isUserTyping= function() {
   var runTwoFunctionWithSleepBetweenThem=function(foo1, foo2, time) {
    $q.when(foo1()).then(() => $timeout(foo2, time));
  }
  runTwoFunctionWithSleepBetweenThem(function (){socket.emit('info_message', { room: $scope.room, msg: 'user is typing...' })},
    function (){socket.emit('info_message', { room: $scope.room, msg: '' });},1500); 
}

}]);
```

html

```
    *<form ng-submit="submit()">
        {{info}}  
        <br>
        <input autocomplete="off" ng-model="insertedText" ng-change="isUserTyping()" type="text" />
            <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">
                Send
            </button>
        </form>*
```

Comment: Which version of IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using lambda expression function, this syntax is ECMA6 syntax, which is not supported at any type of IE....

you should use function expression instead:

```
  var runTwoFunctionWithSleepBetweenThem=function(foo1, foo2, time) {
   $q.when(foo1()).then(function() {
     $timeout(foo2, time);
   });
  }
```

Comment: thanks.. should have known that there will be problem in IE.

also, I wrote your method and now I am getting:

**TypeError: Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference**

can you also help me in understaning why that happens? thanks

Comment: thanks.. it worked. I still new in the promise/$q.when()... syntax.